# Inserting element to immutable LinkedList with final members

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list, trie

I need help with implementing the insert method which adds new child and siblings to the Trie. I saw many solutions. However, my problem is different because the class members inside the class are final so I can't make reference to the next element when I'm traversing the tree. I searched a lot on the internet but seems I can't find any help. I've been struggling with this for two days. In my case, I can't assign current.sibling to newEntry because sibling is final. So I need to find another way to add new elements to the Trie and I have to stick with the following abstract class. Someone advised that I should create new object for each new element, I implemented it, but I don't know why code isn't giving the correct result.

I will share my code below.

Any help will be appreciated

As you can see in the code below members such as sibling are final.

```
public abstract class AbstractTrieChildren implements Iterable<AbstractTrieChildren> {
    /**
     * The label of the outgoing edge.
     */
    protected final char character;
    /**
     * The target of the outgoing edge.
     */
    protected final AbstractTrie child;
    /**
     * The reference to the next sibling or {@code null} if none.
     */
    protected final AbstractTrieChildren sibling;

    public AbstractTrieChildren(char character, AbstractTrie child, AbstractTrieChildren sibling) {
        this.character = character;
        this.child = child;
        this.sibling = sibling;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a new labelled edge ({@link #character}, {@link #child}) to the <b>sorted</b> traversable linked list of siblings iff there is no such edge.
     * If an entry already exists, then this method leaves the list unchanged.
     *
     * @param character the label of the possibly new labelled edge to insert
     * @param child     the target trie of the possibly new labelled edge to insert
     * @return the new head (left-most node) of the <b>sorted</b> traversable linked sibling list
     */
    public abstract AbstractTrieChildren insertSorted(char character, AbstractTrie child);
}
```

Below is all I have tried with the insert method. I don't know why it's not giving the correct result. I have tried using the recursive approach by adding a new element if no element exists, otherwise adding the element to the sibling, but it only adds two elements

```
public AbstractTrieChildren insertSorted(char character, AbstractTrie child) {
        AbstractTrieChildren current = this;


        if (character < this.character) {
            return new TrieChildren(current.character, current.child, null);
        }
        else if (character > this.character) {
            return new TrieChildren(current.character, current.child, new TrieChildren(character, child, null));

        } else {
            return insertSorted(character, child);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is rather confusing. I'm going to address your question by analogy, because I can't be 100% sure what you're trying to accomplish (e.g., what is an AbstractTrieChildren vs an AbstractTrie, etc).

Let's say we wanted to implement an immutable linked list, with a recursion-based insert method.

Our node:

```
public class Node<T> {
  final Node next;
  final T value;
  public Node(T value, Node next) {
    this.next = next;
    this.value = value;
  }
```

Since we cannot update `next`, we need to start an insert operation by creating the end of the list, not the beginning.

```
public Node insertAtEnd(Node current, T newValue) {
  if (current == null) {
    // Base case, we're at the end of the list.
    return new Node(newValue, null);
  } else {
    // Recursive case, get the next node and create a node pointing to it.
    Node newNext = insertAtEnd(current.next, newValue);
    return new Node(this.value, newNext);
  }
}
```

Looking at an example:

- List is initially `(head) 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> null`.
- Call `insertAtEnd(head (1), 4)`.
- `current` is not null, call `insertAtEnd(current.next (2), 4)`.

  - `current` is not null, call `insertAtEnd(current.next (3), 4)`.

    - `current` is not null, call `insertAtEnd(current.next (null), 4)`.

      - `current` is null, return `new Node(4, null)`.
    - return `new Node(3, newNext (4))`.
  - return `new Node(2, newNext (3))`.
- return `new Node(1, newNext(2))`.
- The returned node is now `(head') 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> null`.
- The initial head is still `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> null`, because it's immutable, it wasn't changed.

What you have is more like this (the analogy):

```
public Node insertAtEnd(Node current, T newValue) {
  if (current == null) {
    return new Node(newValue, null);
  }
  else {
    return insertAtEnd(current, newValue);
  }
}
```

You're just calling the method recursively without modifying the inputs, and you're not building any structure out of the recursive call.

Does that make sense?

Your example is more complex, but what you need to do is something like adding more structure to the recursive steps. Like an immutable linked list, you will need to iterate down the original trie structure recursively, then build the new trie structure backward, starting from the leaves and working your way back toward the root.

As for the specifics of where you should be using `[Abstract]TrieChildren` vs `[Abstract]Trie`, I'm unsure about that.

Comment: Hi! Welbog, the insert method should insert the character and the child into the sibling which has the type AbstractTrieChildren, so I think I should create an object of type AbstractTrieChildren and add the character and the child to it for the first element. However, for the next element which is the sibling, I need to create a new Object of type AbstractTrieChildren and add all the previous elements to it, but I don't know how can I implement this using recursion.

Comment: The examples you gave me are helpful but I want to know how to apply them to my situation. Someone told me that I should recreate all objects up to the point where a new element should be inserted but I want to know how to apply this. It seems I can't figure it out. Any help would appreciated